# How to fix NoForeignKeysError

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I keep getting this error:

> "sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition
>   between parent/child tables on relationship Parent.children - there
>   are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing
>   columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or
>   specify a 'primaryjoin' expression."

I followed the guides in the SQLAlchemy documentation but I am still getting this error.

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text) #maybe add unique
    children = db.relationship('Child', backref='parent', cascade = "all, delete-orphan", lazy='dynamic')

def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

def add(self, parent):
    db.session.add(parent)
    return session_commit()


class Child(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Parent.id'))

def __init__(self, name, parent):
    self.name = name
    self.parent_id = parent

def add(self, child):
    db.session.add(child)
    return session_commit()
```

It looks correct to me based on the guides online but I can't seem to find the relationship problem.

Additionally, shouldn't

```
parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Parent.id'))
```

be

```
parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id'))
```

where parent is the table name? I get an error where it tells me that "relation 'parent' does not exist"

Answer (score 1):

You set the table name of Parent model use **tablename**="parent". So the define of parent_id should be parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey("parent.id")). And you can define a relationship named parent in Child model or assign the foreign key of children relationship in Parent model by set the value of foreign_keys in the define of children relationship.